# Missing XML tags when the .xml files are extracted from webservice and viewed on Android

Tags: android, xml, web-services

This is my first time using a webservice and I' trying to create a webservice that sends .xml replies (with tags) to the android device.

When I was browsing through the .xml url through my browser, all the tags are nicely presented. However when I'm browsing the same .xml url through my android devices, all tags have been removed and it is just space separated values.

Is it common for it to happen ? Is the Xml tags actually still present but just made "invisible" when viewing on android devices ? Would it make any difference when i parse it on the device ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the viewer you're using. Some of them show XML without any information how to display it (called XSLT) the way you describe it – the tags itself are not visible, only the text inside them (similar to what happens when unknown elements are encountered in HTML). If you want to write an application for android that parses the XML, it's going to read it normally, with all the tags intact.